# Unit step response of $p(D) = D+kI$ without initial condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The full problem description is: $p(D)=D + kI$ where $D = \frac{d}{dt}$ and $I$ is the identity operator, $k$ is a constant number and $k \neq 0$. Find $x(t)$ such that $p(D) \, x = u(t)$ where $u(t) = 1$ when $t > 0$ and $u(t) = 0$ when $t < 0$, specifically $u(0)$ is $undefined$ (the step function).

Here's what I've tried:

Using ERF, for t > 0, to find a particular solution $p(D) \, x_p= 1 = Be^{at}$ where $B=1, a=0$, thus $x_p = \frac{Be^{at}}{p(a)} = \frac{1}{k}$. To find a common solution for the homogeneous equation I have $\dot{x_c} + kx_c = 0$ which gives $x_c = Ce^{-kt}$ where $C \neq 0$.

Hence finally I get $x=x_c + x_p = Ce^{-kt} + \frac{1}{k}$ for $t > 0$.

This is an MIT OCW homework practice(http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/assignments/MIT18_03S10_pset_06.pdf), in that assignment, the answer to this question is given as $x=\frac{1}{k}(1 - e^{-kt})$ for $t > 0$ where $C$ seems to be specified by $x(0^+) = 0$ (answer in the same document, Part I, 24, a).

I couldn't find clues that support this specification of $C$. Can anyone explain why this is required or provide any reference for implicit requirement of solving unit step response?

Comment: Your solution is good (although we later find a nice Laplace transform technique here). The assumption $y(0)=0$ is just a customary practice. In the absence of other data this gives a nice steady state solution which we can then add transient solutions if need be. Often the long-term behavior is of primary interest to this custom focuses us on what matters most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insistence of $y(0^+)=0$ is a custom. This gives a standard particular solution which allows you to fit any given initial conditions to the homogeneous solution. Also, we can find this particular particular solution by integrating the Green's function. Basically, this choice of initial conditions makes the theory for the transfer function work out nicely. It allows us to separate the transient and steady-state solutions based at time $t=0$. See http://www.supermath.info/TransferFunctions.pdf for a bit on why it is nice to assume zero initial conditions. I think Zill's text has a good section on all this as well, and I also looked at Ritger and Rose's classic text as well as Ostberg et al https://books.google.com/books/about/Elementary_differential_equations_with_l.html?id=6zrvAAAAMAAJ

Comment: Thanks for the answer and references!